How do I change to a full path directory (with spaces) I cut and pasted into Powershell without using wildcards * or shortnames ~?
I am trying to change to a full path directory in Powershell cut and pasted from a windows explorer path but it keeps returning a "cannot find path [...] because it does not exist" error.
I am in the directory:
C:\Users\Nakie\

I want to go to the following working directory so I copy and paste it in the command line prompt:
cd W:\_DITRH\__Featured Video Placeholder\__TISTL\10 [20151228] TISTL Sofia Smallstorm 10

It then says it is an invalid directory. I have tried to add double quotes in various places but can't get it to work in one shot. I can get there one step at a time which is tedious and time consuming.
The following attempts did not work:
cd "W:\_DITRH\__Featured Video Placeholder\__TISTL\10 [20151228] TISTL Sofia Smallstorm 10"
cd W:\_DITRH\"__Featured Video Placeholder"\__TISTL\"10 [20151228] TISTL Sofia Smallstorm 10"
cd W:\"_DITRH\__Featured Video Placeholder\__TISTL\10 [20151228] TISTL Sofia Smallstorm 10"

This does work but defeats the goal of just pasting in the path with minimal required alterations:
cd W:\"_DITRH\__Featured*\__TISTL\10*"

I have tried other combinations including using the apostrophe ' and back-tick ` but can never seem to get this to work in one shot without using wildcards * or the ~ short name to overcome the spaces.

You appear to have noted the issue with the spaces in the file path, but other characters in this path are also causing problems, including the square brackets. The simplest solution is to tell PowerShell that the path is literally a path, literally.
So, use the 'LiteralPath' parameter:
cd -LiteralPath 'W:\_DITRH\__Featured Video Placeholder\__TISTL\10 [20151228] TISTL Sofia Smallstorm 10'


You need to use the single quote character ' as the path contains spaces and escape the brackets using the backtick `
cd 'W:\_DITRH\__Featured Video Placeholder\__TISTL\10 `[20151228`] TISTL Sofia Smallstorm 10'

